# Could it be a negative exclamatory sentence?

Tags: exclamatives

I learnt about the 4 types of sentences: *declarative, interrogative, exclamatory, imperative*. I remember that declarative, interrogative and exclamatory can be either **positive** or **negative**. But I don't have an idea about **exclamatory sentences** if they can be also **negative** or not. Can exclamatory sentences be also negative?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you mean by a negative exclamatory sentence?

Comment: For example: if I say "You are right." it's considered a positive **declarative** sentence. But if I'd say "You are not right." then it's a negative **declarative** sentence". Now all the examples that I saw for exclamatory sentences are positive. I didn't see negative exclamatory sentences (=using the word "not" in this sentences). See here: http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/exclamatory_sentence.htm

Comment: Sure.  For example, at https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/sentence-types.html they give the example **I can't find the butter!**

Comment: How about **Not again!**

Comment: Is it not supposed to be a rhetorical  question like "How about not again?!" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rhetorical-question

Comment: Anyway it seems that exclamatory sentence is a kind of declarative sentence but just with exclamation point in the end. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes exclamations can be made by using interrogative word order and there are two forms of these--positive question or negative question exclamations--both indicating **a positive assertion**.

Examples of using the positive question form of exclamations:

> Have I got news for you!
>
> Was the dessert delicious!

Examples of using the negative question form of exclamations:

> Isn’t it a warm day!
>
> Wouldn't it be lovely!
>
> Aren’t they kind!
>
> Hasn’t she grown!

**A sidenote:**

Accoring to [this site](https://www.englishpractice.com/improve/exclamatory-sentences-verb-patterns/),  British speakers often use negative question forms in exclamations whereas Americans often use non-negative question forms in exclamations:

> Boy, did I make a mistake! (US)
>
> Boy, didn’t I make a mistake! (GB)

Answer (score 0):

All of these 4 types of sentences (declarative, interrogative, exclamatory, imperative) can be either positive or negative.

Examples for negative exclamatory sentences are as the follow:

- "I **can't** find the butter!" (credit: @stangdon and [this site](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/sentence-types.html))
- "I do **not** go there!"